# Change which paper-tabs displayed on-click data binding - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, polymer

I am wanting to dynamically change the paper-tabs that are displayed in my page when the buttons on the sidebar are selected.

ie. (selection | tabs to display)

Expert | 3 tabs

Admin | 4 tabs

etc.

I have managed to get data binding working when I select the tabs themselves with regards to the data shown within the scrollable dialog, I'm just stuck on this.

**page-tabs.html**

```
<!-- THIS IS STILL A PRETTY BASIC EXAMPLE --> 
<paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" noink>
   <paper-tab link>
      <a href="#tab1" tabindex="-1">TAB 1</a>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab link>
      <a href="#tab2" tabindex="-1">TAB 2</a>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab link>
      <a href="#tab3" tabindex="-1">TAB 3</a>
    </paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
    <div>CONTENT OF PAGE 1</div>
    <div>CONTENT OF PAGE 2</div>
    <div>CONTENT OF PAGE 3</div>
</iron-pages>
```

**side-bar.html**

```
<div class="drawer-content vertical layout" id="drawer">

      <div class="userItemInfo horizontal layout">
        <img id="avatar" class="userAvatar" src="../images/hipster.png" slot="item-icon"></img> 
        <div class="userDetails vertical layout" id="userDetails">
          <div class=username>USERNAME</div>
          <div class="subheader">further function</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <paper-icon-item on-click="{{homePage}}">
        <iron-icon icon="home" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span>Home</span>
      </paper-icon-item>
      <paper-icon-item on-click="{{expertPage}}">
        <iron-icon icon="done" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span>Expert</span>
      </paper-icon-item>
      <paper-icon-item on-click="{{searchBar}}">
        <iron-icon icon="search" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span>Search</span>
      </paper-icon-item>
      <paper-icon-item on-click="{{adminPage}}">
        <iron-icon icon="supervisor-account" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span>Admin</span>
      </paper-icon-item>
      <div class="flex"></div> <!-- THIS IS THE ONLY WAY THAT I COULD GET THE LAST ENTRY TO BE FLEXED TO THE BOTTOM -->
      <paper-icon-item on-click="{{settingsPage}}">
        <iron-icon icon="settings" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="">Settings</span>
      </paper-icon-item>

    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your tabs page with `<iron-pages>`, e.g.

```
<iron-pages selected="[[page]]">
    <!-- Expert | 3 tabs -->
    <page-tabs-expert></page-tabs-expert>
    <!--- Admin | 4 tabs -->
    <page-tabs-admin></page-tabs-admin>
    <!-- etc. -->
    <page-tabs-etc></page-tabs-etc>
</iron-pages>
```

And, make your sidebar select-able with perhaps `<iron-selector>`, https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-selector

```
<iron-selector selected={{page}}>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Frank. I'd figured this out yesterday while playing around with it, but wanted to see somebody else's take.

I'm having a problem where I am trying to link a scrollable region in too, but it doens't seem to want to play nicely at the moment.